# Set multiple const values based on conditional

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, immutability, dry

I want to set multiple values based on a conditional. This code would work:

```js
let a;
let b;

if (fooBar) {
  a = "foo";
  b = "bar";
} else {
  a = "baz";
  b = "Hello world!";
}
```

But I am trying to adhere to FP (immutable variables) and DRY principles.

For one variable, I would do this:

```js
const a = fooBar
  ? "foo"
  : "baz";
```

Can I somehow set multiple variables this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say nothing wrong with using `let` overall, however the answer to your question is:

```
const [a, b] = fooBar ? ["foo", "bar"] : ["baz", "Hello world!"]
```

In this case array destructuring can be used. So we create variables to access array item by index (a is #0, b is #1)

Answer (score 4):

Use a ternary to generate an object or array with the required values, then use  destructuring to assign them:

```js
const fooBar = false

const { a, b } = fooBar ? 
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' } 
  : 
  { a: 'baz', b: 'Hello world!' }
  
console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: Not a lot of saving in code here - it is actually larger than before

Comment: The request was immutable variables, not to save characters.

Comment: Sure. But using an array destructe is so much simpler: `const [a, b] = foobar ? ["foo", "bar"] : ["baz", "Hello world!"];`

Comment: I like the more verbose option, that's not dependent or order, but I've mentioned the array option as well.

Comment: @OriDrori DRY is also a requirement and this does not achieve that.

Comment: The DRYness is in the logic and the assignment. The names of the properties are minor overhead. And again - I did mention arrays as an option. Use whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why everyone is so stuck at destructuring. Doesn't this work for you?

```
const a  = 1 ? 0 : -1,
      b = 0 ? 3 : -1;
```

Comment: Does not fulfil DRY, the conditional needs to be written twice here.

Comment: 1. What if the two variables have independent conditions?

2. Noobish because you create an object in memory, and then cause 2 property access on top of 2 assignments and send it to garbage collection.

DRY is not of any importance whatsoever in the situation of OP.

Comment: The question is specifcally related to if two values need to be set based on the same conditional. Otherwise I would use this solution. Cheers